# amChart and cSlider

Tags: javascript, jquery, amcharts

I am having problems trying to make my amChart and cSlider to work together.

When you click on the first bullet in the amChart it's suppose to go to the first slide in cSlider, and when you click on the second bullet in amChart it's suppose to go the the second slide in cSlider. This is what I've done to at least make the amChart interact with cSlider.

```
 chart.addListener("rendered", zoomChart);
 chart.addListener("clickGraphItem", function(event){
    var tester1 = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
    $(tester1).click();
```

The reason why I am getting the elements by the Tag name is because they don't have a ID or a class when they are not clicked on and I don't know how to fix that either.

Here is the full file for more information.

[Google Drive Link To Download Website](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5NaA3R5-8nZcF9YVHZlUUJaQms/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it using this.

```
chart.addListener("clickGraphItem", function(e){
    if(e.item.index == 0) {
        var tester1 = document.getElementById('button-1');
        $(tester1).click();
    }
```